# Contradictory results between GCC and clang related to [basic.link]/7 in the C++ Standard

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14, linkage

This snippet compiles in clang,

```
namespace A {
    void f() {
        void g();
        g();
    }
}

void A::g() { }
```

but GCC only accepts the code if `g` is defined inside the namespace `A` as follows:

```
namespace A {
    void f() {
        void g();
        g();
    }
    void g() {}
}
```

But I believe there's nothing in [basic.link]/7 disallowing the first snippet above.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[basic.link]/p7, emphasis mine:

> When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found
>   to refer to some other declaration, then that entity is a member of
>   the innermost enclosing namespace. **However such a declaration does not
>   introduce the member name in its namespace scope.**

[namespace.memdef]/p2, emphasis mine:

> Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that
>   namespace by explicit qualification (3.4.3.2) of the name being
>   defined, **provided that the entity being defined was already declared
>   in the namespace and the definition appears after the point of
>   declaration in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s namespace**.

GCC is correct. Your first snippet is ill-formed.

Comment: You're right. I've missed to notice [namespace.memdef]/2. (+1)

Comment: By the way, is there anything actually speaking against locally defined functions? Apparently, local classes can define their member functions locally.

Comment: @Columbo [dcl.fct.def.general]/p2

Comment: @T.C. I wasn't talking about the current standard, but about the possibility of introducing it.

Comment: @Columbo Oh, you mean "is there any reason why we don't have such a feature"?

Comment: @T.C. Yes, or "Is there any reason why we cannot introduce it?" E.g. linkage, or what not.

Comment: @Columbo At this point, with lambdas in the language, I doubt that we'll ever have them, whether or not technically feasible.

Comment: @T.C. I know. That doesn't answer my question though. :) I just wanna know whether there is a fundamental technical reason that doesn't allow us to do it. (Probably not, so nvm.)

Comment: @Columbo I doubt that it's technically infeasible, but you'd presumably have to give them external linkage to match local function declarations, and that can make for some very confusing code.

Answer (score 4):

It seems pretty clear to me from `[basic.link]/7`

> ...However such a declaration does not introduce the member name in
>   its namespace scope.

that clang is wrong. Similarly you wouldn't expect this to compile:

```
namespace A
{
}

void A::foo()
{
}
```